# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select current word?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

In JetBrains PhpStorm, what is the keyboard shortcut to select the current word? (I mean the word where the cursor is)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes there is but it's different from one IDE to another, And here are 3 examples:

- **SublimeText**: *Selection* -> *Expand Selection to Word* (The shortcut will be shown next to it according to your OS)
- **PhpStorm**: *Edit* -> *Extend Selection* (The shortcut will be shown next to it according to your OS)

  - **MAC Extended Selection Shortcut**: ⌥ + ↑
  - **MAC Shrink Selection Shortcut**: ⌥ + ↓
  - **MAC Select all occurrences**: ˄ + Command + G
- **Visual Studio Code**: *Selection* -> *Add Next Occurrence* (The shortcut will be shown next to it according to your OS)

  - **MAC Add Next Occurrence**: Command + D
  - **MAC Select All Occurrences**: Shift + Command + L

Answer (score 48):

**Ctrl + W** selects the current word (Extend selection).

Comment: If you used **Ctrl +  W** multiple times you can use **Ctrl + Shift +  W** shrinks the selection again

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Feb 2022 using PyCharm. It could be different for PhpStorm, but usually JetBrains is pretty standardized across flavors.

Answer (score 20):

`^+G`
it should work across all JetBrains IDEs

Comment: This triggers the "Goto Line" popup.

Comment: This answer works for me in PyCharm Mac in Feb 2022. Cursor is in the middle of a word, press Ctrl-G, word gets highlighted! Then if you hit ' or ", it will surround the word in quotes. Also works for braces.

Answer (score 6):

If you have CamelHumps enabled, `Alt` + `J` will be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

to select the current word in Php storm (if you're using Windows) you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

**you can change it** from: setting → keymap → click the search icon next to the search filed(search by keyboard shortcuts) → type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> → find "*Add Selection for Next Occurrence*" and change the keyboard shortcut of that as you want

Answer (score 0):

For the people that comes here in search of a way to just delete the word you are in the middle of, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> (combining the two shortcuts <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>).

This deletes from the cursor to the beginning of the word (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>backspace</kbd>) and then from the cursor to the end of the word (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux.
Select next word: Ctrl+Alt+J
Select all occurrences of word: Shift+Ctrl+Alt+J